# How can i store my player moves data without writing tons of line of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I was searching on the internet for projects do with python and came up with a Tic Tac Toe game. But now i'm kind of stuck in some part of the code because i can't store the player moves. 
Well, to be honest, i maybe know how to do it, but i'll be using A LOT of if, elif and else. Is there another way i can do it without writing 100+ lines of code just to store some data using my current code?

Ps: It needs to be OOP, as i am learning it right now :l

```
import msvcrt as m # Using it for 'Press any key to continue' thing.

import os
import keyboard

class TicTacToe:
    def __init__(self):
        self.difficultAI = 1
        self.playWith = 1  # 3 = Strings and Numbers

        self.playerOne = None
        self.PlayerTwo = None
    def menuSelection(self):
        os.system('cls')

        print(f'[1] - Play\n'
              f'[2] - Options\n'
              f'[3] - Exit')

        try:
            option = int(input('I\'ll go with '))
        except ValueError as valueError:
            print(f'Invalid Option\n'
                  f'Following error: {valueError}\n'
                  f'Press any key to continue...')

            m.getch() # Waiting for any key to be pressed.min
            os.system('cls')
            objectRun.menuSelection() # Call menuSelection again.


        if option == 1:
            objectRun.play()
        elif option == 2:
            pass
        elif option == 3:
            exit()
        else:
            print(f'You should choose something between 1 and 3, and not {option}'
                  f'Press any key to continue...')

            m.getch()
            objectRun.menuSelection()

    def drawBoard(self, topL='?', topM='!', topR='?',
                        midL='!', midM='?', midR='!',
                        lowL='?', lowM='!', lowR='?'):
        board = {
            'top-L': topL,
            'top-M': topM,
            'top-R': topR,

            'mid-L': midL,
            'mid-M': midM,
            'mid-R': midR,

            'low-L': lowL,
            'low-M': lowM,
            'low-R': lowR,
        }

        print(' {0} | {1} | {2}\n'
              '----------\n'
              ' {3} | {4} | {5}\n'
              '----------\n'
              ' {6} | {7} | {8}\n'.format(board['top-L'], board['top-M'], board['top-R'],
                                          board['mid-L'], board['mid-M'], board['mid-R'],
                                          board['low-L'], board['low-M'], board['low-R']))

    # change that stupid name when done
    def play(self):
        os.system('cls')

        print(f'[1] - Player VS Player\n'
              f'[2] - Player VS Machine\n'
              f'[3] - Return')

        try:
            option = int(input('I\'ll go with '))
        except ValueError as valueError:
            print(f'Invalid Option\n'
                  f'Following error: {valueError}\n'
                  f'Press any key to continue...')
            m.getch()
            objectRun.play()

        try:
            os.system('cls')
            self.drawBoard()
            if option == 1:           
                if self.playWith == 1:  # Numbers

                    isBoardFull = False  # Not using it right now, but ok... I guess.
                    while isBoardFull != True:
                        print('Player 1, it\'s your turn\n'
                            'You can choose between 1 (TOP LEFT) up to 9 (BOTTOM RIGHT)')

                        self.playerOne = int(input('I\'ll go with '))

                        self.playerOptions()

                elif self.playWith == 2:  # Strings
                    pass
                else:  # Strings and Numbers
                    pass
            elif option == 2:
                pass
            elif option == 3:
                objectRun.menuSelection()
            else:
                print(f'You should choose something between 1 and 3, and not {option}'
                      f'Press any key to continue...')

                m.getch()
                objectRun.play()

        except:
            print('ERROR AT LINE 126, GO FIND WHAT IS WRONG')

    def playerOptions(self):
        if self.playerOne == 1:
            os.system('cls')
            self.drawBoard(topL='X')
        elif self.playerOne == 2:
            os.system('cls')
            self.drawBoard(topM='X')
        elif self.playerOne == 3:
            os.system('cls')
            self.drawBoard(topR='X')
        elif self.playerOne == 4:
            os.system('cls')
            self.drawBoard(midL='X')
        elif self.playerOne == 5:
            os.system('cls')
            self.drawBoard(midM='X')
        elif self.playerOne == 6:
            os.system('cls')
            self.drawBoard(midR='X')
        elif self.playerOne == 7:
            os.system('cls')
            self.drawBoard(lowL='X')
        elif self.playerOne == 8:
            os.system('cls')
            drawBoard(lowM='X')
        elif self.playerOne == 9:
            os.system('cls')
            self.drawBoard(lowR='X')
        else:
            pass

    def options(self):
        os.system('cls')

        print(f'[1] - Difficult\n'
              f'[2] - P\n'
              f'[3] - Exit')

        try:
            option = int(input('I\'ll go with '))
        except ValueError as valueError:
            print(f'You should choose something between 1 and 3, and not {option}'
                  f'Press any key to continue...')

            m.getch()
            objectRun.menuSelection()


        self.difficultAI = int(input('[1] - EASY\n'
                                '[2] - MEDIUM\n'
                                '[3] - HARD\n'
                                'I\'ll go with '))

        self.playWith = int(input('[1] - NUMBERS\n'
                                '[2] - STRING\n'
                                '[3] - BOTH\n'
                                'I\'ll go with '))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    objectRun = TicTacToe()

    objectRun.menuSelection()
```

Comment: Can you just use a list for each player and append each *move* to the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the current board as dictionary within `self`.

Initialize your board with the default starting characters.

```py
    def __init__(self):
        self.difficultAI = 1
        self.playWith = 1  # 3 = Strings and Numbers
        self.playerOne = None
        self.PlayerTwo = None
        self.board = {'topL':'?', 'topM':'!', 'topR':'?',} #fill in the rest
```

Your drawBoard would need adjusted like this...

```py
    def drawBoard(self):
        board = {
            'top-L': self.board['topL'],
            'top-M': self.board['topM'],
            'top-R': self.board['topR'],
```

And then I would have a separate method for a "move"

```py
def makeMove(self, player, position):
    if self.board[position] not in ['X', 'O']:
        self.board[position] = player
        self.drawboard()
    else:
        # error statement and send back to make a new move...
```

In general, I would have separate methods for the main loop of the game vs everything else. Right now you have a lot of things going on inside the main loop when it should be just sending you to different methods of your game like `playerOptions`, `makeMove`, `drawBoard`, etc. until someone wins or ties.

Comment: Ok, i understood almost everything. But what about the 'player' parameter in makeMove? How would i asign it?

Comment: player could represent the mark for that player, "O" or "X". If you used it directly like I wrote it it should be a string value of some sort, you could rename it to "mark" or something that works for you though.